# Why should I use KVC rather than the simple dot syntax when accessing object properties?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, key-value-coding

There's the option to go the long way, if an receiver class conforms to the NSKeyValueProtocol:

```
[myInstance setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"integerProperty"];
```

or the short way:

```
myInstance.integerProperty = 2;
```

what's the point of this KVC method? When is this useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, those aren't the same, the second should be:

```
myInstance.integerProperty = [NSNumber numbwerWithInt:2];
```

if `integerProperty` is an `NSNumber`.

In general you use the second form when you are doing the most things. You use `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` when you want to dynamically choose the property to store things in. For instance, think about how `valueForKeyPath:` against an `NSArray` works (for reference, if you call `-valueForKey:` against an `NSArray` it will return an array where each object is the result of asking the corresponding object in that `NSArray` for that value:

```
- (NSArray *) valueForKey:(id)key {
  NSMutableArray *retval = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (NSObject *object in self) {
    [retval addObject:[object valueForKey:key]];
  }

  return retval;
}
```

In the above case we were able to use `valueForKey:` to implement our function even though we do not know what the key is beforehand, since it is passed in as an argument.

Comment: "First, those aren't the same, the second should be:" — not necessarily. If you've declared the property as NSInteger or similar, you use just "2" for dot syntax, but must still box it in an NSNumber for KVC.