# Fast enumeration incomprehension

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I found such code on this site:

```
 - (NSArray *) valueForKey:(id)key {
  NSMutableArray *retval = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (NSObject *object in self) {
    [retval addObject:[object valueForKey:key]];
  }

  return self;
}
```

Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't figure out what is fast enumerated there, as self is just an object, not a collection.

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything useful.  For example, it builds a `retval` array, then doesn't even return it, returning `self` instead.

Comment: Just for reference, this code seems to be from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164072/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any class that conforms to the [NSFastEnumeration protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) can be enumerated with the `in` syntax. The code snippet you posted implies that the class also implements the `-countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` method defined by the protocol, and that that method returns an array of NSObject instances to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

Its the `for ( ... in ... )` loop.

`NSMutableArray` must conform to the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

Comment: for (key in dictionary)
I understand what is happening when we are enumerating a dictionary, but whtat is happening when we enumerate self ?

Comment: @user801255 - it looks like the dictionary supports it too.

Answer (score 0):

If your example works then it means that `self` is an instance of a class that implements `NSFastEnumeration`. This is the protocol that needs to be adopted to allow fast enumeration.

You could for example create your own custom object and implement that protocol. Then inside that class you would be able to call

```
for (id obj in self) {
```

this would result in the following method being called on your class, which is defined in the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol

```
countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:
```